# Can't access to snap NextCloud

Tags: snap, nextcloud

I installed NextCloud as snap package in a Raspberry (Ubuntu Server):

```
costales@raspberry:~$ ls /snap/ | grep nextcloud
nextcloud
costales@raspberry:~$ snap list | grep nextcloud
nextcloud          11.0.1snap3  863  nextcloud   devmode
costales@raspberry:~$
```

I associated a local alias to the Raspberry's IP in my PC:

```
costales@dev:~$ grep cloud /etc/hosts
192.168.1.75    cloud
costales@dev:~$ ping cloud
PING cloud (192.168.1.75) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cloud (192.168.1.75): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=9.30 ms
64 bytes from cloud (192.168.1.75): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.72 ms
^C
--- cloud ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.725/7.014/9.303/2.289 ms
costales@dev:~$
```

But when I'm trying to access from my PC to http://cloud.local but I'm getting a 404 error (and browser after the error is adding www to the URL too).

[image]

Any idea please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the server respond if you use the raw IP address rather than host name?  is the service running?

Comment: No way to access the nextcloud web. I tried to install apache and the raw IP showed the apache default page. How can I check if the service is running?